# node.JS how to stop a never ending request?

Tags: node.js

I got this simple script ulizting express framework and node-mysql. Basically, the code listens to request from client, if there is request it will make query to database. then without further ado it just sends a message feedback back to the client.

Problem, the message feedback never go to client because the request never close. You can run the code and see what i'm actually talking about, the database login in the code is valid. Before run you need "npm install express" and "npm instal mysl". save the code to a file and run it in nodejs. Then open browser enter adress localhost:4000

```
 var mysql = require('mysql').Client,
    express = require('express');

//databse work
var client = new mysql();
client.host = '112.78.2.135';
client.user = 'vietnaml_craig';
client.password = 'camera';
client.database = 'vietnaml_db';
client.connect();

var app = express.createServer();

//prepare to create server session for the user
var store = new express.session.MemoryStore;
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({ 
    secret: 'something', 
    store: store
}));
//tell server listen to get request from client
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    client.query(
        'SELECT * FROM user_cookie ',
        function selectCb(err, results, fields) {
                res.header('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
                res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
                res.send('go to go');
                res.end();
            console.log(results);
            client.end();
        }
    );

});
app.listen(4000);
```

Comment: Have you checked whether any response is provided by the database? Try adding `if (err) {
      throw err;
    }` in your `selectCB` function and see if the query is executed correctly.

Comment: hi I edited the code, you can run it and get data from my database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran your code and commented out `res.end()` and it works for me on my computer

```
function selectCb(err, results, fields) {
            res.header('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
            res.send('go to go');
            // res.end(); <- not needed?
        console.log(results);
        client.end();
    }
```

Comment: try to refresh the browser a couple time you will see another problem.

Comment: @runrunforest i also commented out `client.end();` to be able to make multiple requests without restarting node